# How to fill min value in sql and php?

Tags: php, sql, min

I have a table in SQL:

Table 1

```
date       name  s1   s2   s3   s4   min_value
7/10/2017  ram   10   11   12   13   11
7/10/2017  tom   17   16   15   14   16
7/10/2017  ara   13   9    26   22   9
```

If I total all fields in a single date then

```
s1 total value 40
s2 total value 36
s3 total value 53
s4 total value 49
```

Here `minimum value` is 36. It means `minimum value` column is `s2`.

I inserted s2 field value in `min_value` field respectively.

My question is `how will I fill min_value field?`

Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are your ids?how do you associate rows from the first table with the second one ?

Comment: My friend, I do not know how will I associate two table. Please help me.

Comment: I have clarified my problem and edited my question. Now plz  help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code to achieve that:

```sql
SELECT [date], s1, s2, s3, s4,
    case when s1 < s2 and s1 < s3 and s1 < s4 then s1
         when s2 < s1 and s2 < s3 and s2 < s4 then s2
         when s3 < s1 and s3 < s2 and s3 < s4 then s3
         else s4 end as [min_value]
FROM (
    SELECT [date], sum(s1) AS s1, sum(s2) AS s2, sum(s3) AS s3, sum(s4) AS s4 FROM [Table1]
    GROUP BY [date]
) AS A
```

Comment: Friend, I want to fill the commission field as 40 and 56 respectively in table 1. Please show me the code with value from the tables. Thanks in advance.